# Rails accepts_nested_attributes_for - Simple Forms form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, simple-form

I have the following AR models:

```
class Branch < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :branch_delivery_schedules, :class_name => 'BranchDeliverySchedule', :foreign_key => :branch_id

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :branch_delivery_schedules, :allow_destroy => true
end


class BranchDeliverySchedule < ActiveRecord::Base

    validates :opening_time, :closing_time, presence: true

    belongs_to :day_of_week, :class_name => 'DayOfWeek', :foreign_key => :id_day_of_week
    belongs_to :branch, :class_name => 'Branch', :foreign_key => :branch_id
end
```

A branch has many delivery schedules (one per day, M to S).

So, in the branch's form when I'm trying to create a new branch I set the simple_fields_for for the BranchDeliverySchedules.

```
<%= simple_form_for(@branch, html: { class: 'form-foodwish' } ) do |f| %>

    <%= f.error_notification %>

    <!-- BRANCH FIELDS... -->
    <% (1..7).each do |w| %>

      <%= simple_fields_for 'branch[branch_delivery_schedules_attributes][]', BranchDeliverySchedule.new({ day_of_week: w, opening_time: '11:00', closing_time: '11:00' }) do |p| %>

        <%= p.input :id, as: :hidden %>

        <%= p.input :branch_id, as: :hidden %>

        <!-- DAY OF WEEK PLACEHOLDER -->
        <%= p.input :day_of_week, as: :hidden, input_html: { value: w } %>

        <%= p.input :opening_time,  as: :time, html5: true %>

        <%= p.input :closing_time,  as: :time, html5: true %>

      <% end %>

    <% end %>

<% end %>
```

Then I have the strong parameters in my controller:

```
def branch_params
  params.require(:branch).permit(:id, ..., branch_delivery_schedules_attributes: [ :id, :opening_time, :closing_time, :day_of_week, :branch_id] )  
end
```

And everything is working fine, the 7 delivery schedules are being created. The Questions are:

1.- How can I show the Branch delivery schedule validation errors? (Right now it just silently fails, doesn't let me save the branch which is good but I need to show the validation errors)

2.- How can I preserve the values in my `simple_fields_for`?, when I submit the form the values in the time pickers are lost.

Thanks, let me know if you need more information.

Rails version: 4.2.6

Simple form version: 3.4.0

Answer (score 0):

### Controller

```
@branch =  Branch.new
(1..7).each { |w| @branch.branch_delivery_schedules.new(day_of_week: w, opening_time: '11:00', closing_time: '11:00') }
```

### View

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :branch_delivery_schedules do |p| %>
    <%= p.input :day_of_week, as: :hidden, input_html: { value: p.object.day_of_week } %>

    <%= p.input :opening_time,  as: :time, html5: true %>

    <%= p.input :closing_time,  as: :time, html5: true %>

  <% end %>
```